# mips 32 not printing integer value

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

So I am just learning MIPS 32 and am stuck with getting an integer value from the user, and then printing it back. Here is what I have:

```
.text

    main:
    la $a0, str1  #put the address of the string to display in register $a0
    li $v0, 4     #move 4 to the register $v0. This is the system service to display string messages
    syscall       #system call to output str1

    li $v0, 5     #load system service to read integer
    syscall       #Integer inputted is saved to register $v0
    sw $v0, x     #store contents of $t0 into x, x = $t0

    la $a0, x     #put the address of x to display in $a0
    li $v0, 4     #4 = system service to display strings
    syscall       #system call to output x


    .data
    x: .word 0
    y: .word 0
    z: .word 0
    str1: .asciiz "Please enter the value for X:";
    str2: .asciiz "Please enter the value for Y:";
    str3: .asciiz "Please enter the value for Z:";
```

Inputting 1 prints 'r' to the console window.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we're talking [MARS](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html), call 5 will return an integer in `$v0` whereas call 4 prints a NULL-terminated ASCII string. An integer is not a NULL-terminated ASCII string.

You probably want to replace the final call with a call to service 1 and the calue of `x` rather than its address. So:

```
lw $a0, x     #load the value of x to display in $a0
li $v0, 1     #1 = system service to display an integer
syscall       #system call to output x
```

Comment: `$a0` should be set to the actual value to print, not its address.